# Format a dynamic range of data to text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a string of numbers into 9 digit text. The column will vary in length every time this is run.

Tried using a similar method to finding the LastRow.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data Validation")

Sheets("Data Validation").Select

Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

LastRow = ws.Cells.find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), 
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
MatchCase:=False).Row

Set rng = Cells(LastRow, 15)

Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""000000000"")"
Range("O2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:rng")


End Sub
```

I'd like my text format to extend down the entire column of existing numbers. Currently I'm getting a Method Range of Object _Global failed error message.

Comment: `Range("O2:O" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""000000000"")"` No need to `Select` or `AutoFill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `Select` or `AutoFill`.

Change the following:

```
Set rng = Cells(LastRow, 15)

Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""000000000"")"
Range("O2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:rng")
```

to

```
ws.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""000000000"")"
```

It's my own preference to avoid `FormulaR1C1`:

```
ws.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=TEXT(K2,""000000000"")"
```

Comment: Good answer. Would evaluate be a good alternative to include in your answer and avoid formulas alltogether?

Comment: @JvdV probably, as long as OP doesn't actually need the formula. Feeling slightly lazy.... so if you add I'll upvote :)

Comment: Haha I'm not even close to a pc, a comment will have to do lol =)